# Import script from another script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, google-colaboratory

I have imported a repo using git and when I try to run a file, it shows that "it could not be resolved".
The running script has:

```
import craft_utils
import test
import imgproc
import file_utils
```

The imported things are all script.
I have attached the screenshots for the error and hierarchy.
[image: Error screenshot]
[image: Files Hierarchy]

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Which is "the running script"? How do you run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding an empty file named `__init__.py` in the root folder `CRAFT-pytorch` (instead of the `basenet` folder)

Comment: thank you, it worked as per your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

create a empty file named `__init__.py`
it would solve the issue

Comment: Hi, its already there in the basenet folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a file inside of the folder called `__init__.py`

Comment: Hi, its already there in the basenet folder.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an empty file named `__init__.py` in the folder `CRAFT-pytorch`

Second add these line at the top of the file you're trying to running, before the imports:

```
import os
import sys 
import inspect

app_path = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
main_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(app_path))
sys.path.insert(0, main_dir)

import craft_utils 
import test 
import file_utils
```